# How and where can Xamarin downloaded and installed for my existing Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, msdn

**Context:**

Microsoft bought Xamarin and announcement published that every Visual Studio, from the free Community edition right up to the Enterprise edition, now has access to the Xamarin tooling so that developers can build applications for Android and iOS. The product was historically restricted to only support small executables, with anything larger requiring a paid license. **That's not the case today;** even Visual Studio 2015 Community has no size or other restrictions. Some **enterprise-oriented Xamarin features** are still restricted, and developers will **need a Visual Studio Enterprise subscription** to use these.

**Issue/Question**

I would like to install full Xamarin tools (no size restrictions, and with all enterprise features). I have an MSDN Enterprise subscription so I have VS 2015 Enterprise (update 1) already installed on my developer machine.

Unfortunatelly I can not find out how to do this, what and where to download

**What I've done so far**

- I've searched for Xamarin web site. Besides of the following I did not find anything:

  - old "Pricing" menu (which is obviously not applicable now)
  - the very detailed online license, referring to 10+ other sublicense
  - ASP.NET server error messages [like this: MSDN Exlusive](https://www.xamarin.com/msdn-exclusive)
- I've also logged in to my MSDN subscription and looked for keyword Xamarin in the subscribers downloads. Found nothing.

Maybe I missed something.

Comment: http://aka.ms/xam1 (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/xamarin-vs)  Proceed to signin and install it. Since you are running an Enterprise version of VS, the Profiler and Inspector will be enabled.....

Comment: Thanks. Based on the text it seems as a complete install of VS not a feature extension. It also does not say anything about Enterprise features vs free features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> even Visual Studio 2015 Community has no size or other restrictions

it does have restrictions - it is available for individuals, small teams and non-profits etc. from what I remember, not for bigger companies

to install the Xamarin Tools now, try going to Add/Remove Programs dialog and select to Modify/Uninstall Visual Studio (and of course at the dialog shown don't uinstall, but select more features to install). If you already had Xamarin there and it shows constraints to its usage, you should be seeing an item saying "(Update)" and one saying "(Removed)" or something like that. You only keep the "(Update)" one. If not, then deselect the Xamarin option from there to uninstall it from Visual Studio, then repeat the process to install the latest one again

btw, this info I got from Microsoft while troubleshooting some problematic VS installation (http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2499536/c-net-and-windows-10-sdk-failed-to-install) might also be helpful if you have problems with installing Xamarin:

> 1) Delete potentially old versions of Xamarin cached in: C:\Users\All
>   Users\Microsoft\VisualStudioSecondaryInstaller\14.0\installers -- you
>   should see a XamarinVSV1 folder in there, please delete it.
>
> 2) Try running VS Setup again, do a Modify and add Xamarin.
>
> If the above doesn't work, please try to install Xamarin bits directly
>   from the Xamarin MSI (assuming you have already installed all other
>   dependencies like Android SDKs, etc from VS Setup) from here:
>   http://download.xamarin.com/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.0.3.214.msi

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is it your self experience and did you tried this?  or is this information published somewhere?

Comment: it was said by Microsoft Visual Studio PM on Channel 9

Comment: the PM I had mentioned was Amanda Silver btw, remembered her name from this article she posted the other day: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/04/27/xamarin-evolve-whats-next-for-visual-studio-and-xamarin/

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin website states several benefits in different sections:

[Visual Studio Now Includes Xamarin](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/)

> For developers on the Mac, Xamarin Studio is now available as a benefit of your Visual Studio Professional or Enterprise subscription.

[FAQ](http://Live%20Inspector%20(Preview)%20and%20Memory%20Profiler) **(maybe this what you are looking for)**

> Most Visual Studio subscribers should log in to the Visual Studio subscriber portal (or, if you are a Visual Studio cloud subscriber, log into my.visualstudio.com) to access Xamarin Studio (for OS X).

[TestCloud Pricing](https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud#pricing)

> Visual Studio Enterprise customers receive a 25% discount

[Some other benefits](https://store.xamarin.com/) if you contact them for a quote.

And even in the [FAQ](https://www.xamarin.com/faq#xpq7), they list more benefits, such as Advanced tooling (Live Inspector, Memory Profiler)

Comment: Luis, I've asked "how to install" if I have an existing VS 2015 installation and asked not about the product features and benefits....